# Wrong spectrogram in voice message sent with Telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

I'm using the following code:

```
bot.send_voice(message.chat.id, audio.data)
```

Bot sends voice message:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClbQz.png)
But actually it should be something like this:
[correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko1FF.png)

Am I doing something wrong? Can I fix it somehow?

upd: Also, the length of the message seems to be wrong too